# library not found

Tags: homebrew

I compiled a library called libflite (https://github.com/festvox/flite) from source. `make install` automatically installed into `/usr/local/bin` and `usr/local/lib`. A homebrew formula for libflite does not exist.

Next, I tried unsuccessfully to install ffmpeg via a custom homebrew tap

`brew install homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg --with-libflite`

It cannot find libflite:

```
ERROR: libflite not found
Error: homebrew-ffmpeg/ffmpeg/ffmpeg 6.1-with-options did not build
```

Do installers not automatically look for dependent libraries in `usr/local/lib`?

I looked in the ffmpeg `configure` file and the declarations section does have a default library path variable:

```
# installation paths
prefix_default="/usr/local"
bindir_default='${prefix}/bin'
datadir_default='${prefix}/share/ffmpeg'
docdir_default='${prefix}/share/doc/ffmpeg'
incdir_default='${prefix}/include'
libdir_default='${prefix}/lib'
mandir_default='${prefix}/share/man'
```

So why isn't the linker finding it? Isn't `usr/local/lib` the correct directory for all user installed libraries. Does MacOS not come set up to use it by default?
If not, then is there a "correct" way I should be installing libraries to make sure future CLI installations work properly?